# Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. Please answer where is my mistake

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace EX_02_04
    {
        public class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int hexNum = 2015;
                Console.WriteLine("|0x{0,-8:X|", hexNum);
                double fractNum = -1.856;
                Console.WriteLine("|0,-10:f2}|", fractNum);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I am running this code, facing some error like below:

> Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>
> at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
> at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
> at System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine(String format, Object arg0)
> at System.IO.TextWriter.SyncTextWriter.WriteLine(String format, Object arg0)
> at System.Console.WriteLine(String format, Object arg0)

Can you please answer me where the problem in the code is?

Comment: `"|0x{0,-8:X|"` is not a valid format string. What you probably want is `Console.WriteLine("0x{0:X}", hexNum)`. I'd suggest to use string interpolation instead, so this becomes `Console.WriteLine($"0x{hexNum:X}");`

Comment: Thank @marc_s for reply... I have used "|0x{0,-8:X|" this code because i want the result inside the vertical bar or middle of the both v-bars. can you suggest me how to process this for same result as i want?

Comment: @HarleyKolmint: I have not replied - you should direct your comment at user "PMF" instead ....